# mpv doesn't play audio from mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp4, mpv

Troubles with mp4 files captured from webcam.

I capture video from my webcam with **vlc**. The captured file is played without issues in **vlc**, but **mpv** could not play audio stream.(**ffmpeg** also doesn't recognize audio codec)
How can I resolve these issues?

Logs:

---

```
 $ vlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.5.1 Umbrella (revision 2.2.5.1~ppa)
```

```
$ ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vn -acodec mp3 -ab 320k -ar 44100 -ac 2 output.mp3
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --disable-ffserver --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x37cae40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: none (mp3  / 0x2033706D), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 128 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41avc1
    creation_time   : 2021-01-19T11:39:31.000000Z
    playback_requirements: QuickTime 6.0 or greater
    playback_requirements-eng: QuickTime 6.0 or greater
    encoder         : vlc 2.2.5.1 stream output
    encoder-eng     : vlc 2.2.5.1 stream output
  Duration: 00:00:12.79, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1882 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: none (mp3  / 0x2033706D), 44100 Hz, mono, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-01-19T11:39:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 864x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:5], 1746 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1000k tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-01-19T11:39:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (? (?) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Decoder (codec none) not found for input stream #0:0
```

```
$ mpv test.mp4 
Playing: test.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (mpeg4 24.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) ( 1ch 44100Hz)
Failed to initialize a decoder for codec ''.
Audio: no audio
VO: [gpu] 864x480 yuv420p
V: 00:00:01 / 00:00:12 (11%)


Exiting... (Quit)
```

---

Sample video
http://transfer.sh/OZHYo/test.mp4

4.4.0-142-generic #168~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. Upgrade your ffmpeg and mpv.